# subscriptionInvalidArgument: Your request is invalid for this subscription purchase. (Google::Apis::ClientError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this working with my react-native project on the frontend but I cant seem to validate purchases on the backend. is there anything glaring I am doing wrong here?

I'm using `gem 'google-api-client'`

also, I have an app in internal testing if that matters, this is only trying to validate subscription with google IAP

Here is my current code:

```
require 'google/apis/androidpublisher_v3'


  class GooglePlayService
    def initialize(package_name, purchase_token, product_id)
      @package_name = package_name
      @purchase_token = purchase_token
      @product_id = product_id
      @android_publisher = Google::Apis::AndroidpublisherV3::AndroidPublisherService.new
      @android_publisher.authorization = authorize
    end

    def authorize
      key_file_path = Rails.root.join('config', 'keys', 'google', 'xxxxx.json')
      json_key = File.read(key_file_path)

      Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
        json_key_io: StringIO.new(json_key),
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'
      )
    end

    def query_subscription
      @android_publisher.get_purchase_subscription(
        @package_name,
        @product_id,
        @purchase_token
      )
    end

    def query_product
      @android_publisher.get_purchase_product(
        @package_name,
        @product_id,
        @purchase_token
      )
    end
  end
```

and here is how i query an example transaction

```
service = GooglePlayService.new('com.xxx.xxx', 'hmgccjeedhfjbahhbcinbjbo.AO-J1OxSl_Ir1YnoodqVDcXIJWopC-v1NgYKZZhVrr6l4qQ78tjKWPG_LDhViph-pniR83SjE8VmqJr-60VhZV5nPAndhxUSCw', 'weekly_subscription_3')

service.query_subscription
```

and here is the truncated output

```
["Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"], ["Content-Encoding", "gzip"], ["Date", "Wed, 17 May 2023 00:27:43 GMT"], ["Server", "ESF"], ["Cache-Control", "private"], ["X-XSS-Protection", "0"], ["X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN"], ["X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff"], ["Alt-Svc", "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000"], ["Transfer-Encoding", "chunked"]], @dumped=false> body: "{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 400,\n    \"message\": \"Your request is invalid for this subscription purchase.\",\n    \"errors\": [\n      {\n        \"message\": \"Your request is invalid for this subscription purchase.\",\n        \"domain\": \"androidpublisher\",\n        \"reason\": \"subscriptionInvalidArgument\"\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n">

/home/noobskie/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/google-apis-core-0.11.0/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:239:in `check_status': subscriptionInvalidArgument: Your request is invalid for this subscription purchase. (Google::Apis::ClientError)
```

Comment: Did you find the reason? I am facing the same error.